# Converting an int to String(Java)

Tags: java, string, class, int

Let's say I run on a for with i from 0 to 6, each run in the for I initialize a class that gets as a parameter a name, ex:

```
ClassThing[] a = new ClassThing[6];
for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    a[i] = ClassThing( "hello" );
}
```

So I want each cell to have it's name by the order, **a[0].name** will be **0**, **a[1].name** will be **1** and on.

How do I use i variable for this?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand _I want each cell to have it's name by the order,_.

Comment: Please add more code. In this form, it is not entirely clear what you'd like to achieve, and what exactly is not working as you want it to.

Comment: `a[i].name = i.toString();`?

Comment: Then it's just `a[i].name = Integer.toString(i);`

Comment: I got it now, thank you. Make this comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as said before, you can either use

```
a[i].name = Integer.toString(i);
```

or

```
a[i].name = ""+i;
```

or any other mentioned way;

Answer (score 3):

You should try something like:

```
a[i].name = String.valueOf(i)
```